# Accessing `this` in react when assigning method to an event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Apologize in advance, I am very new to React.

In `printDocument` I am setting the `oHiddFrame.onload = this.setPrint;`  even to `this.setPrint` but am getting an error of `Cannot set property '__container__' of undefined` for `this` in `setPrint` on the first assignment.

I am setting `onClick={this.printDocument.bind(null, this.props.document.view_href)}` on button in render(). How do I bind "this" to the actual event I'm assigning it to?

Much appreciate any help or advise.

```
  closePrint: function () {
    document.body.removeChild(this.oHiddFrame.__container__);
  },

  setPrint: function () {
    this.contentWindow.__container__ = this;
    this.contentWindow.onbeforeunload = this.closePrint;
    this.contentWindow.onafterprint = this.closePrint;
    this.contentWindow.focus();
    this.contentWindow.print();
  },

  printDocument: function (url) {
    var oHiddFrame = document.createElement("iframe");
    oHiddFrame.onload = this.setPrint;
    oHiddFrame.style.visibility = "hidden";
    oHiddFrame.style.position = "fixed";
    oHiddFrame.style.right = "0";
    oHiddFrame.style.bottom = "0";
    oHiddFrame.src = url;
    document.body.appendChild(oHiddFrame);
  },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **ES5** (*classic*) Javascript :

```
onClick={this.printDocument.bind(this, this.props.document.view_href)}
```

In **ES6** (with *babel* (https://babeljs.io/)) Javascript :

```
onClick={() => this.printDocument(this.props.document.view_href)}
```

ES6 fat-arrows auto-bind *this* context to the function, and add more readability to code.

**More informations :** http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_arrow-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

Your onClick needs to look like this: `onClick={this.printDocument.bind(this)}`, otherwise it won't bind to the button correctly.

Inside `printDocument()` method, you can always call `this.props` and use whatever you need in there. You can also manipulate the event right inside the method afterward.

Not sure if that's what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

Pass `this` as the first argument to [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind). The first argument is the context, what `this` should be inside the bound function, but you're currently passing `null`.

```
onClick={this.printDocument.bind(this, this.props.document.view_href)}
```

The event object, a [`SyntheticMouseEvent`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html#mouse-events) instance, will be the last argument to your handler. You can add another argument to the function declaration and reference it:

```
 printDocument: function (url, event) {
   ...
 }
```